# Am working on a site using django framework and i got this AttributeError telling me 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

`AttributeError at /polls/

'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Django Version:     2.0.2

Exception Type:     AttributeError

Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.4.egg\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26

Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe

Python Version:     3.4.1

Python Path: ['C:\Users\WUESE PHILIP\Desktop\vibezt',

'C:\Python34\python34.zip',

'C:\Python34\DLLs',

'C:\Python34\lib',

'C:\Python34',

'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages',

'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.4.egg',

'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.4.egg',

'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytz-2019.3-py3.4.egg']`

`polls urls.py`

`from django.urls import path`

`from . import views`

`urlpatterns = [

path('', views.index, name='index'),

]`

`views.py`

`from django.shortcuts import render`

`from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

```
return("<h2>Welcome to my First Python Django Project</h2>")`
```

`vibezt urls.py`

`from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path`

`urlpatterns = [

path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),

path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]`

Answer (score 0):

You should return `HttpResponse` (or subclass) in your views, not ***raw*** python strings.

So you should have:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Welcome to my First Python Django Project</h2>")
```

Comment: working i appreciate

Comment: Glad to help. Please always look for similar questions before asking so that you don't get a negative feedback from the community; also consider marking the answer as accepted.